# How to deal with bad contiguous edges for 3d printing

Tags: objects, edges, 3d-printing

I was trying to model my object for 3d-printing and faced this problem. I use `3D Printing Toolbox` in `Blender v2.79`. And checking my object for manifoldness, it shows me that I have `Bad Contiguous Edges`. I don't know what to do with it.
[image]
On this picture, that edges are selected. And 28 Non Manifold Edges are because I haven't used Mirroring yet.

Answer (score 15):

In Edit mode, I pressed A to select all, then Mesh->Normals->Recalculate Inside.
This fixed it for me as my problematic edges were inside a cylinder recess in my object.

Answer (score 1):

Select the face, then in Face Menu / Face Data, click "Reverse UV". That generally happens when a face is made on the wrong side.

Additionally, you will need to use "Mesh / Normals / Recalculate Outside". Seen that with parts of bottom faces detected as top in STL exports (bad color seen in Cura for the example)

Answer (score -1):

Just re-calculate normals(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> with everything selected in edit mode). That fixed it for me.