# Unwanted hard edges with subdivision modifier

Tags: modifiers, vertices, edges, subdivision-surface

[image]

This happens everytime I merge some vertices and then apply the subdivision modifier. I've tried removing double vertices and even if I delete the edge that seems to be causing the problem this happens:

[image]

It just transfers to the next edge. Does someone know why it looks like it sticks to the original mesh? Any ideas on how to fix it are welcomed!

Comment: It doesn't sticks to original mesh, that's the subsurfed result. Likely the reason are internal faces, you could try to run Select > Select All By Trait > Internal Faces or select manually

Comment: didn't work :( they are pieces that were separated and I merged them vertex by vertex (the 4 corners) and that edge was the result, I don't know if maybe that's the issue...

Comment: You can provide the file using this link: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I can't upload it, it says that "files may take some time to process" but nothing happens

Comment: I don't have any idea what's wrong exactly in your case and what were you merging to; the general principle is that Subsurf creates bulge like on the screenshot if you have: 1. internal face/-s 2. dobles. The can be created by other modifiers as well, depending on the case. In the https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ site you're supposed to include link to the question and press Upload after choosing file, nothing is supposed to happen before that

Answer (score 2):

I may be very, very late to the party but as mentioned this was more than likely due to non-manifold geometry.

In Blender 2.80 I used the advice from an answer that I now cannot find to go to `select>Select all by trait` and then clicked all the options until I discovered some of my verts were non-manifold. The closest approximation to the answer lies [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry) (it gives a shortcut for selecting non-manifold geometry instead).

In the end after discovering by tweaking the settings of the aforementioned `select all by trait` tool that some verts were non-contiguous I asked stack again for the answer and [hey presto!](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117993/how-to-deal-with-bad-contiguous-edges-for-3d-printing), just recalculate internal normals.

**N.B:** this is what worked for me, but tools are linked to deal with identifying your non-manifold topology issue in many scenarios

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have an internal quad, which is made with those edges. If there's a quad, delete it.

Also check the *Mean Crease* of those edges (1 means hard edge, 0 means soft edge):

[image]

Comment: there isn't and mean crease is at 0. This edge is the result of 4 merged vertices, I get something similar everytime I do that...