# Non-manifold face

Tags: topology, geometry, error, loop

I recently resolved a non-manifold issue as detailed in my answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136794/unwanted-hard-edges-with-subdivision-modifier/150420#150420), but I have now made another issue for myself which I cannot seem to resolve.

I have been trying to reduce the amount of extraneous loopcut sections by removing parts I don't need and joining them up like in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ViVKUiG8ks&t=231s) but I failed and I decided I would try and use the knife to connect back up my loopcuts like before.

Everything was mostly ok, but then this face for some reason does not accept the knife tool. I can join the vertices following the knife tool but then these vertices are then highlighted under `select> Select all by trait>non-manifold` (where they can be selected only as 'vertices' within the option checkboxes).

Here are some screenshots of me trying to use the knife over it:

*Drawing with knife*
[image: knife]

*Result*
[image: result]

**edit:**
As requested the file I am working on
[image]

Comment: I've had this issue before, I'm not sure what causes it. :(

Comment: Mind uploading?

Comment: Try to select all and remove doubles (in 2.8 now it's Merge by distance). Another possibility is that the vertex cutting is started from probably isn't part of the edge which is above it; then technically no doubles present but cutting won't work. Check if there's anything non-manifold before cutting. If you'd like to upload the file use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and paste link here

Comment: Just added the file, see the edit

Comment: I don't see anything special about that mesh. It happens that Knife tool won't cut some faces, in this case it might be due to faces being too distorted (non-concave) although not necessarily. You can use Loopcut tool and then join new loop with the window using Vertex Connect Path (shortcut J) like [in example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UhTc.gif)

Comment: I appreciate the advice, I'm still learning so knowing [ctrl + J] is useful, but it didn't resolve my issue unfortunately. The wierd thing is that even though I technically have n-gons I do not get any-non-manifold geometry via 'Select all by Trait' *scratches head*